# QT Linguist tool not picking up right translation

Tags: ubuntu, qt, qtcreator, qt5

I am trying to use Translation feature in QT. There are more than 4000 translation needed to be done for one language. And I have to do this for more than 15 different languages. So, I decide to write `language.ts` files by shell scripts. After generating my `language.ts` succesfully, I open the file in notepad++ (in windows) and I can see the expected translation in the file. For example, in Brazilian language, following is the translation code is `language.ts`file:-

```
<message>
<location filename="temp_unit.ui" line="59"/>
<source>Cancel</source>
<translation>Отказ</translation>
</message>
```

Now when I try open the file in `QT Linguist` tool, I got following error:-

```
Parse error at lang_Brazil.ts:1:38:Encountered incorrectly encoded content.
```

As details provided in [this website][1], I replace encoding value `utf-8` with `ISO-8859-1` .
Now I can open the file in `QT Linguist` but the translation is showing wrong characters, ex:- for Cancel  it is showing `Îòêàç` (expected translation is `Отказ`).

Please confirm why it is not taking right translation in QT linguist while I can see it if I open language.ts file in notepad++.
[1]: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/bi.1111/b32121/pbr_nls003.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

1. do not create `.ts` files with shell script - there is a special tool `lupdate` for that.
2. you mixing languages - there is no such language as "Brazilian". The country of Brazil uses Portuguese (or Brazilian Portuguese variation). What is more confusing in your case - the translation `Отказ` is actually Russian.
3. Code page ISO-8859-1 is for Latin alphabet, so Cyrillic text will be shown as set of random glyphs. If your file is indeed in a one-byte coding, then in order to see Cyrillic, you should use ISO-8859-5 (which is supposed to be used for Cyrillic), but since you see correct glyphs in `Notepad++`, then the most correct codepage, most likely, would be Windows-1251. Also note, that `Notepad++` can work with variable length coding such as UTF-8, in this case using some other encoding would be very wrong. Find "file properties" in Notepad++, it should tell you which encoding is currently in use by the editor.

Read here how to create `.ts` files: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linguist-manager.html

Use `Qt Linguist` to edit `.ts` file - it will automatically put correct code page into the file. Do not use `Notepad++` or any other text editor for this. At least until you know exactly what you are doing and not mixing languages with code pages. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linguist-translators.html

Comment: Actually, there are around 80000 translations that I need to add. Doing it manually won't be possible.

Comment: Eighty thousand languages? Are you sure aliens would be interested in earthly applications? By the last count, Earth has just over 7 thousand languages and dialects. Where did other 73 came from?

Comment: there are 20 languages, each language have 4000 translations. Total 80000 translations.